# Why will modal popup be visible on default in mobile? And why won't it work as intended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

my modal popup window, when it loads on mobile, is visible on default so that when a page loads, at the top of the page the modal popup is there even if i didn't click on the button that is supposed to activate it. Plus, the buttons don't work. I thought it must be a problem with the dialog tag and javascript not working on mobile, but how do I fix it? Here is my code:

```
<dialog id="window" style="height:520px;">
    <div id="warning-box">
        <h3>Confirm</h3>  
        <p>Are you sure you want to return to Home? You will be logged out of your account.</p>
        <div id="button-container2">
            <button id="exit" class="popupbutton1">Cancel</button>
            <button id="confirm1" class="popupbutton1">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</dialog>
<script>
        (function () {
            var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
            document.getElementById('show').onclick = function () {
                dialog.show();
            };
            document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function () {
                dialog.close();
            };
            document.getElementById('confirm1').onclick = function () {
                dialog.close();
                location.href = "../Account/Login/logout.php";
            }
        })();
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery Mobile, the dialog widget is deprecated now ([details here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/)) and there is a new way. Sample code below, and try it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quilkin/4LynjL3L/2/). Note also, that using jQuery you can replace all your 'document.getElementById' calls by '$.' which makes for easier reading!

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
  <button id="showDialog" class="popupbutton1">Show Dialog</button>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="dialogPage">
<div id="warning-box">
     <h3>Confirm</h3> 
    <p>Are you sure you want to return to Home? You will be logged out of your account.</p>
    <div id="button-container2">
        <button id="exit" class="popupbutton1">Cancel</button>
        <button id="confirm1" class="popupbutton1">Yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#showDialog').click(function () {
  $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#dialogPage", {
    role: "dialog"
  });
});

$('#exit').click(function () {
  $("#dialogPage").dialog("close");
  alert('cancelled');
});
$('#confirm1').click(function () {
  $("#dialogPage").dialog("close");
  alert('confirmed!');
});
```

(edit:) you can still do it with the dialog widget, see this  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quilkin/wh86zq5v/)